# mod_rewrite issue Apache behind Nginx

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have nginx proxying to apache as a backend in order for nginx to handle static assets. Unfortunately when I attempt to visit a "pretty url" it just displays the index page.

nginx config

```
server {
        listen   80;

        root /var/www/example.com;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        server_name example.com www.example.com a.example.com b.example.com c.example.com;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {

                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        }

         location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
}
```

Apache vhost config

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080>
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAlias www.example.com
        ServerAlias a.example.com
        ServerAlias b.example.com
        ServerAlias c.example.com

        ServerAdmin info@example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com

        <Directory /var/www/example.com>
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/5r_error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/5r_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/maintenance.html -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/maintenance.html
RewriteRule ^.*$ /maintenance.html [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http%2://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example-old.co.uk [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example-old.co.uk [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^servers/([^\/]+)/?$ servers.php?scroll-to-server=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^media/([0-9]+)$ media.php?media-id=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^media/([a-z,]+)$ media.php?filter=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^manage/?([^\/]+)$ admin.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^operations/?([^/]*)(.*)$ operations.php?c=$1&m=$2 [L,QSA]

ErrorDocument 404 /error
ErrorDocument 403 /error

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

When I visit `example.com` it loads fine, when I visit `example.com/test` it just shows the homepage still. The request in chrome for the page returns 200.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `try_files` changes the URL to `/index.php` in order to send it upstream which looses the *pretty permalink*.

You might try to send the *pretty permalink* upstream by adding a named location. Maybe:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @proxy;
}

location @proxy {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
}
location ~ \.php$ {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
}
```

See [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) and [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

Comment: After changing to this apache/nginx started serving the page up for download (php source was being downloaded).

Comment: @GreenGiant Understood. I have updated the answer with two proxy locations.

Comment: Thanks for your solution!!! Just spend hours trying to figure out what I was doing wrong before i found this entry.

Comment: How about getting this to work with HTTPS?